# Jena recursive reasoning issue

Tags: jena, reasoning

In the below example, the infM doesn't infer that {r myProperty v}, any ideas why?

However, it does infer that {r owl:sameAs r1} from the mySameAs asserted statement. But if I write:

```
this.infM = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MINI_RULE_INF, this.baseM);
this.infM = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MINI_RULE_INF, this.infM);
```

then it also outputs that {r myProperty v}

### Example code:

```
this.baseM = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
this.infM = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MINI_RULE_INF, this.baseM);

OntResource r = baseM.createOntResource(null);
OntResource r1 = baseM.createOntResource(null);
OntProperty myProperty = baseM.createOntProperty("http://example.com#my_property");
OntResource v = baseM.createOntResource("http://example.com#a_value");
OntProperty mySameAs = baseM.createOntProperty("http://example.com#mySameAs");
baseM.add(mySameAs, RDFS.subPropertyOf, OWL.sameAs);

r1.addProperty(myProperty, v);
r.addProperty(mySameAs, r1);

infM.rebind();

assertTrue(infM.contains(r, myProperty, v));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. I've logged it as [jena-61](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-61) on the Apache Jena Jira.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad this got acknowledged. Now, waiting for the fix :)